# Understanding password profiles settings

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I've one question it is related to Oracle DBA, I've just read about password settings in profiles concept, i'm little bit confusing on PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX and PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME, and I understand something about these two topics. I updating here what i'm understand when I was reading about this, so tell me is it right or wrong.

1)  PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX: This setting is used for reusing of old passwords. The functionality of this setting is restricts reusing of old password for some days.
Example:
Sql> alter profile default limit PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX 180;

For suppose my current password is ‘abc123’, just now I changed it as ‘xyz123’. After very few days I want change ‘xyz123’ password as ‘abc123’ old password, but in PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX setting have 180 days value. So now I able to change ‘xyz123’ to ‘abc123’ old password the above setting is not allowed, because only I can use ‘abc123’ as new password after 180 days only.

2)  PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME: This is also used for password reusing purpose. The functionality of this setting is, it decides after how many password changes we can set old password as new password. 
Example:

Sql> alter profile default limit PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME 5;

So now I can reuse old password after 5 password changes, I explain it with example, my old password is ‘abc123’ and just I’ve changed it into ‘xyz123’, after some days I want to change my current password ‘xyz123’ to ‘abc123’, but above setting doesn’t allows to change it. when I change the passwords 5 times with different passwords 6th time it allows ‘abc123’ as a new password.

please share your answer
Thanks
Bhagya Raj

Answer (score 0):

Is it so difficult to refer documentation?

`PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX` in simple terms is the maximum number of times passwords MUST be at least changed in order to reuse an old password again.

`PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME` is the restriction on number of days before which you cannot use the same password again.

Usually, both these two parameters must be set in conjunction with each other.

For example, if you specify PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME to 30 and PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX to 10, then the user can reuse the password after 30 days if the password has already been changed 10 times.

So, you create your profile as,

```
CREATE PROFILE new_profile
  LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX 10
        PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME 30;
```

Comment: Thank You so much Lalit Kumar